# Timestamp for Edits Made to 1 Cell Only

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have this script that works perfectly for any edit on the spreadsheet page:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (!e.value) return;
  e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange('F29')
       .setValue(new Date());
}
```

However, when I try to modify it so that it only works with edits made to cell C29 (which is actually C29:E29 merged; I don't know if that matters), it won't update when there are edits made to that cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (!e.value) return;
  e.source.getCell('CONTENTS','C29:E29')
       .getRange('F29')
       .setValue(new Date());
}
```

I've tried it with both C29 & C29:E29 for getCell; neither works, so there's obviously something wrong and I'm out of ideas for how to make it work correctly. I'm sure there's an easy answer though...

@Rubén - this is the change I tried:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (!e.value) return;
  e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C29'
       .getRange('F29')
       .setValue(new Date());
}
```

I also tried this just in case it was an issue with the merged cells:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (!e.value) return;
  e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C29:E29'
       .getRange('F29')
       .setValue(new Date());
}
```

[Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/170ZsrI1n5Fq4Ln6tyUEs-voyFSHdbQruwTtxxP4d8kA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It looks that you missed "You could the above as the condition of `if`, `switch` among other JavaScript control statements."

Comment: I thought it was the condition as it's the next line following my " if (!e.value) return; " line. Should " e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C29' " be inside the brackets of that if statement then instead of a line below it? If that's not it, I don't know what it should be or how to fully implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you are trying to use getCell as it was the same as the [CELL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en) built-in spreadsheet function, but it isn't, actually the [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) hasn't a getCell method.

To make a function that only works when C29 is edited use the following condition or something equivalent:

```
e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C29'
```

You could use the above as the condition of [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) among other JavaScript [control flow statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling).

Comment: Tha would definitely explain why getCell wouldn't work, thanks :). I did try replacing that line with the one you suggested, but that doesn't work either. No changes are made to the 'timestamp' cell when I edit C29.

Comment: Sorry, thought that was clear...

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
   if (!e.value) return;
  e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C29'
       .getRange('F29')
       .setValue(new Date());
}

Comment: Done... added a link to a tester file as well.